# Facebook messenger extension js doesnt load when there is adsense code

Tags: facebook, adsense

I am having a webview for my facebook messenger bot , but i am putting a google adsense ad inside the webview. However , there is a problem that when I am putting the ad , messenger extensions isn't calling the function

```
<script>
  window.extAsyncInit = function() {
    // the Messenger Extensions JS SDK is done loading 
  };
</script>
```

although i am doing everything as per the documentation . I don't know whats the issue of google adsense , is it stopping the async process inside the page ?

Answer (score 0):

window.extAsyncInit will not fire when **messenger_extensions** is false.

Property **messenger_extensions** must be true if using Messenger Extensions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/url-button

```
"buttons":[
      {
        "messenger_extensions": true,
        "type":"web_url",
        "url":"https://petersfancyapparel.com/criteria_selector",
        "title":"Select Criteria",
        "webview_height_ratio": "full",

        "fallback_url": "https://petersfancyapparel.com/fallback"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: But I am not opening it from a button , I added it as an extension and it's being opened from the chat extensions tab ,so facebook is opening it not me.

Comment: Could you provide the URL for testing?